# how to group an array of objects by the same value of a specific key field without using external libraries?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, function, javascript-objects

I have some data that is an unorganized javascript object of objects that have the same keys, with potentially different values:

```
const raw_data = {
   "sweets":[
      {
         "flavor":"chocolate",
         "product":"icecream",
         "price":3
      },
      {
         "flavor":"vanilla",
         "product":"icecream",
         "price":3
      },
      {
         "flavor":"chocolate",
         "product":"candy",
         "price":1
      },
      {
         "flavor":"chocolate",
         "product":"shake",
         "price":5
      },
      {
         "flavor":"vanilla",
         "product":"candy",
         "price":2
      },
      {
         "flavor":"strawberry",
         "product":"icecream",
         "price":3
      }
   ]
}
```

What I want is a new object where the new object has it's keys being the unique values of the `flavor` variable from the objects of the `raw_data` object, and the values of this new object are the same as `raw_data`, but they are organized into arrays. and these arrays are assigned the key that is the value of the array's object's `flavor` variable. Example below:

```
const cleaned_data = {
   "chocolate": [
     {
         "flavor":"chocolate",
         "product":"icecream",
         "price":3
      },
      {
         "flavor":"chocolate",
         "product":"candy",
         "price":1
      },
      {
         "flavor":"chocolate",
         "product":"shake",
         "price":5
      },
   ],
   "vanilla": [
     {
         "flavor":"vanilla",
         "product":"icecream",
         "price":3
      },
      {
         "flavor":"vanilla",
         "product":"candy",
         "price":2
      },
   ],
   "strawberry": [
     {
         "flavor":"strawberry",
         "product":"icecream",
         "price":3
      }
   ]
}
```

Could someone please provide a function that would able to do this without using 3rd party libraries?

Comment: What have you tried? Show us and we could help with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `reduce()`.

```js
const raw_data = [
  {
     "flavor":"chocolate",
     "product":"icecream",
     "price":3
  },
  {
     "flavor":"vanilla",
     "product":"icecream",
     "price":3
  },
  {
     "flavor":"chocolate",
     "product":"candy",
     "price":1
  },
  {
     "flavor":"chocolate",
     "product":"shake",
     "price":5
  },
  {
     "flavor":"vanilla",
     "product":"candy",
     "price":2
  },
  {
     "flavor":"strawberry",
     "product":"icecream",
     "price":3
  }
]

const group = raw_data.reduce((result, row) => {
  if ( !result.hasOwnProperty(row.flavor) ) {
    result[row.flavor] = [];
  }
  
  result[row.flavor].push(row);
  
  return result;
}, {});

console.log(group);
```